# Angular 2 router class instance

Tags: javascript, angular

Sorry in advance. I'm new to Angular so I'm sure i just don't know enough vocab to google the correct thing. I'm trying to make a simple CRUD app but my edit functionality is not working.

**Problem**

1. No matter what row i click from my dashboard, when the edit view shows it always has the same values in the form inputs. When I log the routerParam in `edit.component.ts -> ngOnInit()` it always has the same value, but my `dashboard.component.html` template looks like it should provide the correct parameter to the `gotoEdit` method. Am I doing something wrong with my binding?
2. In `edit.component.ts -> ngOnInit()` I'm getting the error message `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Row'.` I have tried casting the `email` routeParam to a `Row` and creating a new `Row` instance with the values from temp, but both failed.

Ideally I would like bypass the `gotoEdit` method and have the `DashboardComponent` pass the row to the `EditComponent`'s `email` property, but I have no idea how to.

**Router Config**

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/dashboard',  name: 'Dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent ,  useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/insert',  name: 'Insert',  component: InsertComponent },
  { path: '/edit/:email',  name: 'Edit',  component: EditComponent }
])
```

**Row Class**

```
export class Row {
    PK: number;
    BudgetCenter: string;
    EmailAddress: string;
}
```

**Dashboard.component.html**

```
<p>All Emails</p>
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Budget Center</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th><a (click)="gotoAdd()" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let email of emails">
            <td>{{email.PK}}</td>
            <td>{{email.BudgetCenter}}</td>
            <td>{{email.EmailAddress}}</td>
            <td>
                <a (click)="gotoEdit(email)"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                <a (click)="deleteRow(email)" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { EmailService }  from './email.service';
import { Row } from './row';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  emails: Row[] = [];

  constructor (
      private emailService: EmailService,
      private router: Router ) {
  }

  gotoAdd()
  {
    this.router.navigate(['Insert']);
  }

  gotoEdit(row: Row)
  {    
    //this.router.navigate(['Edit', row]);
    console.log('in gotoEdit()');
    this.router.navigate(['Edit', {email: row}]);
  }

  deleteRow(row: Row)
  {
    let index: number = this.emails.indexOf(row, 0);
    if (index > -1) {
      //console.log('found it', index);
      this.emailService.deleteRow(row);
      this.emails.splice(index,1);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.emailService.get().then(emails => this.emails = emails);
  }

}
```

**edit.component.html**

```
<form *ngIf="email" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputBudgetCenter" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Budget Center</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input [(ngModel)]="email.BudgetCenter" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBudgetCenter" placeholder="Example: B001">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input [(ngModel)]="email.EmailAddress" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Example: joe@clemson.edu">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button (click)="updateRow()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**edit.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { RouteParams } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { EmailService }  from './email.service';
import { Row } from './row';

@Component({
    selector: 'edit-row',
    templateUrl: 'app/edit.component.html',
    inputs: ['email']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() email: Row;

    constructor (
        private emailService: EmailService,
        private router: Router,
        private routeParams: RouteParams) {
    }

    updateRow()
    {
        console.log('in update', this.email);
        /*this.emailService
            .addRow(this.budgetCenter, this.emailAddress)
            .then( ()=> {
                this.router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
            } );*/
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('in edit',this.routeParams.get('email'));
        let temp: Row = this.routeParams.get('email');
        this.email = temp;
        //this.email.BudgetCenter = temp.BudgetCenter;
        //this.email.EmailAddress = temp.EmailAddress;
        //this.emailAddress = temp.;
        //this.budgetCenter = temp.;
        /*   console.log('in edit component init', this.email);
        let temp = JSON.parse(this.routeParams.get('email'));
        console.log('temp', temp);
        this.email = new Row(temp.PK, temp.BudgetCenter, temp.EmailAddress);
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: you should try to use the new router. There is no point to use the deprecated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only pass the id of the current email through the router, and then get it from your `EmailService` by that id.
like maxisam suggests you can use the new router and then you will get the changes of the route inside `EditComponent` as an Observable.

something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .params
      .subscribe(params => {
        const id = +params['id'];
        this.emailService.get(id)
          .then(email => {
            this.email = email;
          });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any other solution other than requesting the information again? I already have the data in the app, It seems wasteful to request it again.

Comment: Before you performed an edit, wouldn't you always *want* to get the most current version of the data? The user could have had the data displayed on the dashboard all morning, then click to edit one. To prevent concurrency issues, it seems that you would always want to get just prior to the update?

Comment: The second function on the service will give you the email from a list that you already fetched from the server. When you get the data from the server you store it with an array on the service.